# Event reservation email markup not recognize "action" attribute

Tags: google-schemas

I create an email that with Microdata for EventReservation. When I receive mail Gmail recognizes properly the information about the event date, place, etc. But I added a custom *action* to go a web page that Gmail don't recognized. I this *action* attribute of Event still supported by Gmail. Microdata looks like this:

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
    <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="1000"/>
    <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed">
    <link itemprop="modifyReservationUrl" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/1000">
    <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Name"/>
    <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Action">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Go to my web site"/>
        <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/action"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Event name"/>
        <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2020-09-01T18:00:00+0000"/>
        <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2020-09-01T19:00:00+0000"/>
        <div itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Event Performer Name}}"/>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Address name"/>
            <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="Address">
                <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Locality">
                <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="Region"/>
                <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="PostCode">
                <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="Country">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```